# wpf skipping if even though condition is true

Tags: c#, wpf

a simple IF function written for testing, the condition is clearly true, but it just skips to ELSE every time.
Could somebody tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

```
namespace SANK
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for SignIN.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class SignIn : Window
{
    string username;
    string password;
    string user = "user";
    string pass = "pass";
    public SignIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LogInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        password = PassBox.ToString();
        username = UserBox.ToString();
        bool jednako = String.Equals(password, pass, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        bool jednako2 = String.Equals(username, user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (jednako&&jednako2)
        {
            SignedIn.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            Wrong.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of `LogInButton_Click(...)` and see where it's going wrong using your debugger

Comment: _" the condition is clearly true"_ - not so fast young Padawan. Did you make _sure_ it is using a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using `TextBoxes`? If so, change it to use the `.Text` property:

```
password = PassBox.Text;
username = UserBox.Text;
```

Comment: I was using `PasswordBox` for the password one. I changed it to `TextBox` and it works now, thanks.
But how do I make the text appear as dots in the`TextBox` ?

Comment: @ElbaTrams that's a bit more complicated, as you will need to create a mask. If you want to change the password to be a PasswordBox, you can get the password by using PassBox.Password instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call toString method on a class the output of password & username

```
password = PassBox.Text;
username = UserBox.Text;
```

are "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox" which doesn't make any sense!! In order to access to the value of textbox you need to call TextBox.Text property.

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 0):

You can still use PaswordBox, but to get text from Passwordbox you have to use this:

`password = PassBox.Password;`